# Has anyone used tools like (Chef, Salt, Puppet, CfEngine) to configure a 2008 Win Server with Sql?

Tags: windows, configuration, sharepoint

I have been looking into tools to automate the creation of servers. 
For two different reasons:

- Production
- Development machines

I love the idea of the [immutable server](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ImmutableServer.html).

I have seen the tools demoed and used successfully on *nix boxes
running Rails or Lamp etc.

Has anyone found a good way to do this in the Microsoft stack?

I would like to get in on the fun and create scripts that will
install Windows, patch it according to specification, deploy Sql Server
create scripts to build out a database and just for fun deploy SharePoint
and configure it, and then deploy a SharePoint solution to it.

I can get part of the way, install Windows manually, install Sql Server
manually, use Powershell to do all the configuration and setup.
Install SharePoint and configure part of it, then powershell for the rest
of the configuration and deploying a solution.

I would love to have the ability to run one script though, or at least
one unified process.

I can, and have mostly used VM template images and then instantiated them, 
but the creation of the template is usually a manual step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, these tools (a least the ones that work on windows) are perfectly capable of getting SQL Server installed and running, and doing any further configuration work that's needed.

For instance, Puppet Labs maintains a module that will install SQL 2008 R2, [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mssql).  You may want to tweak it for your own purposes (like if you want to use a non-local service account, or enable mixed mode authentication), but it certainly does the job.

Comment: Thank you. How about scripting the Windows install itself?

Comment: @Development4.0 The install of the configuration management tool?  Absolutely, it should be rolled into your provisioning process.